# система не обновляется

Tags: updates

system: elementary OS 5.0 Juno HP-Convertible-x360-11-ab1XX

when trying to update, an error message is displayed:

> Failed to receive updates. This may be caused by external (manually added) repositories or a damaged source file."
>   Details: "E: Repository« http://ppa.launchpad.net/slonua/rtl8821ce/ubuntubionic Release ”does not contain the Release file.
>   W: Updating from this repository cannot be performed in a secure way, so it is disabled by default.
>   W: For information on creating a repository and user settings, see the apt-secure (8) reference page.

It all started with WIFI not working after installation. OS doesn’t see Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter after Dancing with Tambourines start WIFI, however, bluetooth did not work and there was a problem with the updates.

---

система: elementary OS 5.0 Juno
HP-Convertible-x360-11-ab1XX
при попытке обновления выводится сообщение об ошибке: "Не удалось получить обновления. Это может быть вызвано внешними (добавленными вручную) репозиториями или поврежденным файлом с источниками."
Подробности:
"E: Репозиторий «http://ppa.launchpad.net/slonua/rtl8821ce/ubuntu bionic Release» не содержит файла Release.
W: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
W: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8)"
Началось все с того, чтобы после установки не работал WIFI. OS не видит сетевой адаптер Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter
После "танцев с бубнами" удалось запустить WIFI, однако bluetooth так и не заработала и появилась это проблема с обновлениями.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've incorrectly added a PPA. Take a look in `/etc/sources.list.d` and remove anything that has `slonua` in the filename. That PPA only builds for `zesty` (17.04) which is EoL and unlikely to fix problems with this specific wi-fi card.